# Search in the adobe Reader doesn't work

Tags: pdf, viewers

(This question is only as reference, I will add the answer myself)

Suddenly the search in the expl3 documentation `interface3.pdf` no longer works. As an example searching for "divis" gives this as the first hit:

[image]

In sumatra there is no problem, other files (e.g. source3.pdf) works fine. What could be the reason?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is the search cache of the adobe reader. After the last update of l3kernel it leads to wrong search results. Emptying the cache solved the problem for me:

[image]