# beamer, searching in beameruserguide

Tags: pdf, documentation

for reading and searching for some phrase in packages documentation i use Acrobat Reader DC. it works fine for all packages except for `beamer`. in it only occasionally i find searched phrase, mostly results shows non related phrase in documentation pdf file. for example:

[image]

i wonder, if someone else experienced similar problems. is there a way to correct this behavior?

Comment: Clear the cache of the Acrobat Reader. I have this problem occasionally as well. In my Reader version there is a button in the `Preferences->Search` menu called `Purge Cache Content`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407788/search-in-the-adobe-reader-doesnt-work

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it helps. but i wondering why this problem i have only at `beamer` and not at other packages?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you very much for help.

Comment: @Zarko: As far as I understand Reader keeps a 'Fast search index' on a per - file base -- this can be very huge in case of such files as the `beamer` documentation because that file is very 'large', so this can get out of sync. Smaller pdf files do not screw up the search index, most likely

Comment: Perhaps you just got a beamer update and did do a lot of search in the pdf before.

Comment: hm, most of serch i do in `tikz & ogf` manual, really huge documentation and always work fine. so i suspect that is something special in `beamer` documentation. now i will every time before searching in `beamer` documentation purge cache content.

Comment: @Zarko: Well, you could increase the cache as well...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, now is set to 100 MB. what you suggest fo appropriate size? do i increase max. number of document returned result (now 500) and range of words for proximity searches (now 900)?

Comment: Viewer problems are off-topic.

Comment: @Zarko TikZ & PGF Manual has not been updated for years (see Ulrike comment above and your reply).

Comment: @HenriMenke I think it's more a duplicate of Ulrike's link.

Comment: @Zarko: I have no suggestion for the number... `100 MB` is the default, as far as I know. This is sufficient for me for quite a while.

Comment: @Zarko As a test you could disable the fast search option - this should prevent this problem but you will have to test if searching is still fast enough for you.